# I want to know the port which the application starts on

Tags: docker, dockerfile, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm running a .Net MVC Core 6 wep app using docker. When I run the application from Visual studio it runs on https://localhost:55004/ and when I run it using the same command from the CMD which is:

```sh
docker run \
  -dt \
  -v "C:\Users\eslam\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" \
  -v "C:\Users\eslam\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" \
  -v "C:\Users\eslam\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" \
  -v "E:\Projects\LatestPOS\LatestPOS\LatestPOS:/app" \
  -v "E:\Projects\LatestPOS\LatestPOS:/src/" \
  -v "C:\Users\eslam\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" \
  -v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" \
  -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" \
  -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" \
  -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" \
  -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" \
  -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" \
  -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" \
  -P \
  --entrypoint tail df88be -f /dev/null
```

And try to go to the same link https://localhost:55004/ it says This site can’t be reached

DockerFile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LatestPOS/LatestPOS.csproj", "LatestPOS/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LatestPOS/LatestPOS.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LatestPOS"
RUN dotnet build "LatestPOS.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LatestPOS.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish


# Run the App
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LatestPOS.dll"]
```

Comment: Your `docker run` command overrides the entrypoint in your Dockerfile, so your app doesn't start at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I removed the "--entrypoint tail" part and still nothing

Comment: Why do you expose port 80 and 443 when your app "runs on" port 55004? Also the `-P` option will "_publish all exposed ports to **random** ports_".

Comment: @HansKilian this was the problem. thanks for your help.

Comment: @rveerd this is the default configurations from visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `docker run` command overrides the entrypoint in my Dockerfile, so my app doesn't start at all.

Thanks for [Hans Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924803/hans-kilian) for the solution.